# Knockout removeAll() not recognised

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, data-binding, knockout.js

I have a page I bind a viewmodel to a HTML table inside a jQuery UI Dialog.

When the user close the Dialog, I want to remove all the element inside the viewmodel `observableArray` bind to the HTML table. I am using the `removeAll()` method, but my firebug told  me that is not recognized as a function.

Can you help me?

This is a simplified scenario.

HTML

```html
<input type="button" id="open" value="GO!"><br />
<div id='hidden'>
    <table>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: i">
            <tr>
                <td><span data-bind="text: code" /></td>
                <td><span data-bind="text: descr" /></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(function () {

    function vm() {
        this.items = [
            {code: "2011",descr: "descr 2011"},
            {code: "2012",descr: "descr 2012"}, 
            {code: "2013",descr: "descr 2013"}
        ];

        this.i = ko.observableArray(this.items);

        this.clearFoundEvals = function()
        {
            this.i.removeAll();
        };

        return this;
    }

    ko.applyBindings(new vm());

    $dialog = $('#hidden').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 200,
        width: 300,
        buttons: {
            cancel: function () {
                vm.clearFoundEvals();
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
           }
        });

        $('#open').click(function(){
            $dialog.dialog('open');
        });    
    });
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/angelobadellino/UXKt9/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't assigned your view model to a variable, so it doesn't exist in the cancel method:

```
var vm = new vm();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wBR6h/)

Comment: When you debug it, what does this.i resolve to? Is it showing up as an observableArray? Also, I'm not fully understanding why you want to call removeAll; that will remove all the items from the observableArray, is that what you really want to do?

Comment: Yes, this is just what I want to do. RemoveAll the element in the observableArray